# dynamically generate formula in excel

Tags: excel, formula

Lets say I have two sets of data and want to compare each row and column to make sure that they are identical.

Both sets of data have the same number of Columns and rows, say first set is Columns A-G, 2nd set of data is on the same tab an goes from H-N (in reality I actually have 50+ columns in each set).

Typically what I do when I don't have a lot of columns, i do something like:

```
=if(AND(A2 = h2, B2=i2, c2=j2),"Good","Bad")
```

Once I have a formula, then I press the little square and drag it down across all rows. This is able to quickly show me whether there is data difference in any of the columns or not.

However in this case I have a lot of columns to compare. Is there a quicker way to do this, or generate dynamically somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:G2=H2:N2))=0,"Good","Bad")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=TEXTJOIN(,,A1:C1)=TEXTJOIN(,,h1:j1)`

This will return either TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Potential for false positives though. Plus TEXTJOIN has a length limit.